# Set RecyclerView's height based on its item's height

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to set height of Recyclerview based on its item's height . Like (item's height * count of items which can be set to any number) should be the height of the RecyclerView when it loads.

I am able to set its height on item click.
 //This is my interface

```
@Override
    public void onSubCategoryClicked(View view, int position) {

            reyclerview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, view.getHeight()*2));


}
```

Now I want to set height of recyclerview when it loads.

Comment: Does it help if you set the height of the RecylerView itself to `wrap_content`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inflate and measure your `ViewHolder` without actually laying it out, this will let you take its size and put it on top of `RecyclerView`.

Note that for this to work properly you must ensure your `ViewHolder` size is not affected by binding data (no resizable images, only textviews with fixed line count etc.) and you only have a single item view type (or at least equal height on all of them).

Inside your activity/fragment after initializing your `RecyclerView`:

```
// create viewholder using adapter - if you have custom view type use it instead of 0
RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = recyclerView.getAdapter().createViewHolder(recyclerView, 0);
// measure item view using recycler views layout manager
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().measureChildWithMargins(vh.itemView, 0, 0);
// now carry over viewholder size onto recyclerView, for example show 5 items
recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = vh.itemView.getMeasuredHeight() * 5;
// finally throw created viewholder into scrap pool so it can be reused
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().putRecycledView(vh);
```

Comment: I will check this

Comment: What is exactly viewType? I am getting exception. https://pastebin.com/H9gigHJR

Comment: you're supposed to run this code block after you setup layout manager and adapter in your `recyclerView`, right now it's crashing because adapter is not set.